# JavaScript hoisting and IIFE

Tags: javascript

I just written an example when learning JavaScript hoisting.

```js
var name = 'world';
(function(){
    if(typeof name === undefined){
    var name = 'Jack';
    console.log('goodbye ' + name);
    }else{
    console.log('hello '+ name);
    }
}
)();
```

In this example, I got `hello undefined`. What makes me confused is that since the `name` is undefined why it didn't log `goodbye undefined` according to the `if` statement?

Thanks!

Comment: `typeof name === "undefined"` - typeof returns a *string*

Comment: typeof returns a string

Comment: Thanks all of you

Comment: You just really don't need to use `typeof` there. Simply compare to `undefined`.

Answer (score 2):

You might check for `undefined` directly.

```js
var name = 'world';

(function () {
    if (name === undefined) {
        var name = 'Jack';
        console.log('goodbye ' + name);
    } else {
        console.log('hello ' + name);
    }
})();

console.log(name);
```

Answer (score 2):

You dont have to use typeof, you can directly check if name === undefined.

```js
var name = 'world';
(function(){
    if(name === undefined){
    var name = 'Jack';
    console.log('goodbye ' + name);
    }else{
    console.log('hello '+ name);
    }
}
)();
```

Answer (score 1):

`typeof` returns a string.

`typeof(undefined) === "undefined" //true`

`undefined === undefined  //true`

more on `typeof`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof

Answer (score 0):

When you fix your logical error, the output is as expected.

```js
var name = 'world';
(function(){
    if(typeof name === "undefined"){
    var name = 'Jack';
    console.log('goodbye ' + name);
    }else{
    console.log('hello '+ name);
    }
}
)();
```